# How do I set location of my .exe program so that visual studio do not add net7.0-windows after that?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

In framework, if I set my program to run on

```
C:\Users\Dropbox\arbitrage2
```

However, after I upgrade to net7.0 my program is run on

```
C:\Users\Dropbox\arbitrage2\net7.0-windows
```

Visual studio add that itself.

What about if I just want it to be run on C:\Users\Dropbox\arbitrage2

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look to this topic from Microsoft :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022

it mention :
Some projects will by default include framework and runtime in the build path. To change this, right-click the project node in Solution Explorer, select Edit Project File, and add the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```